# A matrix of determinant equal to zero raised to a large power

Tags: matrices, determinant

Im given a question where $B$ is a matrix that has elemnts expressed by variable x, the question is to find the solution for $B^{50} (100 , y , z)=(0,0,0)$.
This could be solved by finding the $x$ value which makes the determinent equal to zero but i cant quite understand why.
I can only imagine that there would exist a zero row and with each multiplication this could make a lot of elements equal to zero but i cant exactly decide at which power I can decide thats true.

Comment: How is $B$ defined?

Comment: If you can find $x,y,z$ so that $B(100,y,z)=(0,0,0)$, then you get immediately $B^{50}(100,y,z)=B^{49}(B(100,y,z))=(0,0,0)$. But you don't tell us what $B$ is, so I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: B is 3×3 matrice that has b31=b32= 0 and b33= -20+x after row reduction.

Comment: That doesn't tell us very much.